# Getting "TypeError: undefined is not a function" when trying to send email using mailgun

Tags: javascript, parse-platform, mailgun

I am trying to send an email using mailgun and I have given my code below

```
Parse.Cloud.define("SendEmail", function(request, response) {

    var Mailgun = require('mailgun');
    Mailgun.initialize('domainName', 'myApikey');

    Mailgun.sendEmail({
            to: "test@test.com" , 
            from: "test@test.com",
            subject: "Title",
            text: "Contents"
        },{
        success: function() {
            response.success(request.params);
            console.log("--email sent - success");
            console.log(request.params);
        },
        error: function() {

            console.log("--failed to send email - success");
            console.error(request.params);
            response.error("Uh oh, something went wrong");
        }
    }); 


});
```

but am recieving an error `TypeError: undefined is not a function` in the line `Parse.Cloud.define("SendEmail", function(request, response)` and not sending email, I am new to mailgun and parse, please assist me, thank you in advance

Comment: Then you most likely did not include the _Parse_ library at the correct place.

Comment: @t.niese I have included my parse library in my index file along with my parse key, is that you are refering to?

Comment: @metadings I am very new to mailgun, can you please guide me where I went wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran your code in my own CloudCode instance, and it executes just fine. Could you post your entire main.js file please? There may be a formatting issue or some such.

Comment: I am running the above code when the user clicks a send button in my application and the entire above mentioned code is called in my button click. Is there the place I went wrong?

Comment: Oh. That code will only work on Parse's server. You need to put that function into your main.js file in Parse Cloud Code. The Cloud Code Guide (https://parse.com/docs/cloud_code_guide) will tell you how to access that and upload your code. Then, you will need to call the cloud code function using your button handler. Your button click handler would use code like `Parse.Cloud.run('SendEmail', {}, {
  success: function(result) {
    // result is 'Hello world!'
  },
  error: function(error) {
  }
});`

Comment: Sure John Davis. Thanks and sorry too

Comment: Hey John, I got another doubt.Please clarify this too, Can email be send without domain name using mailgun? please help me Am running out of this issue

Comment: Hi Raj - you definitely need a domain when using Mailgun. Have you read through their setup guide here: http://documentation.mailgun.com/quickstart-sending.html? Adding a domain is (thankfully) straight forward.

Comment: Yes John Davis, I have gone through the documentation and I understood that domain name is essential for sending email using Mailgun. Thank you for replying John Davis